# Eval command does not come with Cygwin?

Tags: shell, unix, cygwin, eval

I'm trying to run a Nodejs project imported from my friend's repo.
He uses Mac and I use windows. It works perferctly on his laptop but not on mine. When I start the server, there are some commands that not work on windows.

```
eval $(cat .env) node ./scripts/run.js
eval $(cat .env) node webpack/webpack-dev-server.js
eval $(cat .env) NODE_ENV=production nodemon -w server -w shared index.js
```

And I learned that cygwin is a good way. After I installed cygwin, I still can not use the eval command.
The error I got there is

```
not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

Does cygwin support this and I somehow didn't activate it?

Comment: eval is a [bash builtin command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-eval) -- what is your error?

Comment: hi glenn, i edited the question

Comment: It looks like either the .env file or your script (or both) has windows `\r\n` newlines. Please confirm with: `od -c .env` -- Use `dos2unix` to fix that.

Comment: I dont fully understand how do the newlines affect?I feel the problem is I dont have the eval command installed with Cygwin.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to run this command with `cmd.exe` and not with `bash`. If you want to run this from `cmd.exe` you would have to run `bash -c "eval $(cat .env) NODE_ENV=production nodemon -w server -w shared index.js"` or similar